# Enter Parameter Value when using SQL in Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update

I keep getting an "Enter Parameter Value" input box when I run this code.

```
Private Sub UpdateTables()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "update tblTest,ImportedTable set tblTest.Unit_Cost=ImportedTable.Unit_Cost where tblTest.Part_No=ImportedTable.Part_No"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Sub
```

The box shows up for `tblTest.Unit_Cost`, `ImportedTable.Unit_Cost`, `tbltTest.Part_No`, and `ImportedTable.Part_No`.

The two tables, `tblTest` and `ImportedTable` exist and are spelled properly. `Unit_Cost` and `Part_No` both have spaces in the field names (I know that's terrible) hence the '_' in referencing them. I tried taking the space out and rerunning the code, but that didn't fix it.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly?
Thanks!

Comment: use `[]` around field names with spaces - e.g. `ImportedTable.[Unit Cost]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MS Access you must enclose field names in brackets `[]` when the field contains spaces.

```
Private Sub UpdateTables()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "update tblTest,ImportedTable set tblTest.[Unit Cost]=ImportedTable.[Unit Cost] where tblTest.[Part No]=ImportedTable.[Part No]"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: You are quite welcome.  Please mark this answer as accepted so that others know a solution has been provided.